Goal tracking app in React
I've developed a goal tracking app in React.
I'm curious whether writing filter functions without using useState is appropriate or not.
Any feedback to optimize the code would be greatly appreciated.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import GoalForm from "./Components/GoalForm";
import Header from "./Components/Header";
import Inprogress from "./Components/Inprogress";
import Completed from "./Components/Completed";

function App() {
  const [goals, setGoals] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("goals")) || []
  );
  const [editingGoal, setEditingGoal] = useState("");

  // Update local storage whenever goals change
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("goals", JSON.stringify(goals));
    console.log(goals);
  }, [goals]);

  const addGoal = (newGoal) => {
    if (editingGoal) {
      setGoals(
        goals.map((goal) => (goal.id === editingGoal.id ? newGoal : goal))
      );
      setEditingGoal("");
    } else {
      setGoals((goals) => [...goals, newGoal]);
    }
  };
  const editGoal = (goalEl) => {
    setEditingGoal(goalEl);
  };
  const changeStatus = (id) => {
    setGoals((goals) => {
      return goals.map((goal) =>
        goal.id === id ? { ...goal, completed: !goal.completed } : goal
      );
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <GoalForm onAdd={addGoal} editingGoal={editingGoal} />
      <div className="goal-list">
        <Inprogress
          goals={goals}
          ongoalEdit={editGoal}
          setGoals={setGoals}
          changeStatus={changeStatus}
        />
        <Completed goals={goals} changeStatus={changeStatus} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


const Completed = ({ goals }) => {
  
  const completedGoals = goals.filter((goal) => goal.completed);

import React from "react";

const Completed = ({ goals }) => {
  
  const completedGoals = goals.filter((goal) => goal.completed);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="completed-container">
        <h1 className="completed-heading">Completed</h1>
        <ul>
          {completedGoals.map((goal) => (
            <li key={goal.id} className="goal-name">
              <p>✔ {goal.goal}</p>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default Completed;


const Inprogress = ({ goals, ongoalEdit, setGoals, changeStatus }) => {
  const deleteGoal = (goalEl) => {
    setGoals(goals.filter((goal) => goal.id !== goalEl.id));
  };
  const inProgressGoals = goals.filter((goal) => !goal.completed);

import React from "react";
import { FaEdit } from "react-icons/fa";
import { MdDelete } from "react-icons/md";
const Inprogress = ({ goals, ongoalEdit, setGoals, changeStatus }) => {
  const deleteGoal = (goalEl) => {
    setGoals(goals.filter((goal) => goal.id !== goalEl.id));
  };
  const inProgressGoals = goals.filter((goal) => !goal.completed);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="progress-container">
        <h1 className="progress-heading"> In progress</h1>
        <ul>
          {inProgressGoals?.map((goalEl) => (
            <li key={goalEl.id} className="goal-name">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={goalEl.completed}
                onChange={() => changeStatus(goalEl.id)}
              />

              <p>{goalEl.goal}</p>
              <div className="btn-container">
                <button
                  className="edit-btn btn"
                  onClick={() => ongoalEdit(goalEl)}
                >
                  <FaEdit />
                </button>
                <button
                  className="del-btn btn"
                  onClick={() => deleteGoal(goalEl)}
                >
                  <MdDelete />
                </button>
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default Inprogress;


full code: https://github.com/devio012/goal-tracker
